# How do I make a ratio image on Erdas Imagine 2014?

Tags: image, erdas-imagine, band

I have a stacked image but want to divide bands 4/5/. I have built a model on the model maker but the resulting image is completely black after running the model. When I open the attributes table the two categories are both "1" and are black

Comment: Perhaps you could post your model?